# Drawing QGraphicsLineItem on a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I have an application where i need to draw lines on a `QTableView` showing the range of frames. I have a `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` which holds a `QTableView`
As shown below:

[image]

**Criteria**

- The span of the lines should stay relative to position of the columns i.e. first line should stay between 3 and 7 all the time even when scrolled out of the view. Should again be visible when scrolled back
- I would like to retrieve the starting index and ending index of the line as in QModelIndex.
- Line must always maintain the center of the width of the row

I have hereby created a MVCE

Mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "timelineview.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    TimelineView* graphicsView = new TimelineView(this);
    setCentralWidget(graphicsView);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

TimelineView.cpp

```
// qt
#include <QHeaderView>

// local
#include "timelineview.h"

TimelineView::TimelineView(QWidget* parent) :
    QGraphicsView(parent),
    m_scene{new TimelineScene}
{
    setScene(m_scene);

    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    m_table = new QTableView;

    // settings for table view
    m_table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
    m_table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    m_table->verticalHeader()->hide();
    m_table->horizontalHeader()->setHighlightSections(false);

    m_tableModel = new QStandardItemModel(10, 100, m_table);
    m_table->setModel(m_tableModel);

    m_scene->addWidget(m_table);

    setMouseTracking(true);
}


void TimelineView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    m_scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, width(), height());
    m_table->setGeometry(m_scene->sceneRect().toRect());
    fitInView(m_scene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

TimelineView.h

```
#ifndef TIMELINEVIEW_H
#define TIMELINEVIEW_H

// qt
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

// local
#include "timelinescene.h"

class TimelineView : public QGraphicsView
{
    public:

        explicit TimelineView(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

    protected:

        virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;

    private:

        QTableView* m_table;
        QStandardItemModel* m_tableModel;
        TimelineScene* m_scene;
};

#endif // TIMELINEVIEW_H
```

TimelineScene.cpp

```
#include "timelinescene.h"

TimelineScene::TimelineScene(QObject* parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
    , m_lineItem{nullptr}
    , m_isPressed{false}
{

}



void TimelineScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        m_origPoint = event->scenePos();
        m_isPressed = true;
    }

    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
}



void TimelineScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(m_isPressed)
    {
        if(m_lineItem == nullptr)
        {
            // create a pen for the line to be drawn
            QPen pen;
            pen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
            pen.setBrush(QColor(255, 102, 0));
            pen.setWidth(8);

            m_lineItem = new QGraphicsLineItem(m_origPoint.x(), m_origPoint.y(), event->scenePos().x(), event->scenePos().y());

            // set the pen
            m_lineItem->setPen(pen);

            // add the item to the scene
            addItem(m_lineItem);
        }

        m_lineItem->setLine(m_origPoint.x(), m_origPoint.y(), event->scenePos().x(), m_origPoint.y());

        update();
    }

    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}



void TimelineScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event)
{
    m_lineItem = nullptr;
    m_isPressed = false;

    QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

TimelineScene.h

```
#ifndef TIMELINESCENE_H
#define TIMELINESCENE_H

// qt
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QGraphicsLineItem>
#include <QPointF>



class TimelineScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    public:

        explicit TimelineScene(QObject* parent = nullptr);

    protected:

        virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) override;
        virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) override;
        virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) override;

    private:

        QGraphicsLineItem* m_lineItem;
        QPointF m_origPoint;
        bool m_isPressed;
};

#endif // TIMELINESCENE_H
```

**Problems:**

- I am not able to get the index of the cell i.e. stating and ending point of the line in terms of QModelIndex
- I could even draw the lines on the `QHeaderView` and also on the `QScrollbar`. I know the reason for this is because the whole canvas is a scene and i can draw everywhere. But i want to restrict drawing only to the cells of the table

I know i could handle all of these issues if i could find a way to retrieve info about the underlying `QTableView` but not sure how.

Comment: Did you consider doing it the way round? Not having a graphics view but having a custom item delegate that will paint the respective parts of the line within the cells? See a basic example of the concept here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html

Comment: Is it possible to draw lines with LMB+Drag using item delegates? I am sorry i have never used styled item delegates before. I will look into the example though.

Comment: You would have to emulate that behavior by overloading mousepressevent, mousereleaseevent, mousemoveevent in the delegates; also make other cells update as well at the same time. It might become ugly again.

Comment: @ypnos Yah you're right! But in future i am planning to add horizontal resizing, selecting and deleting feature for the lines. Do you think item delegates would still be a good plan to go with?

Comment: It's a tough question. Will you run into the situation where the table changes layout on the screen e.g. by column widths being adjusted or rows growing due to word wrap? Then you would have to shift the lines around manually accordingly I assume. If the table is pretty static and predictable, the graphics item approach might be less work.

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed, using a delegate is the right way to do it.

In case it's impossible for some reason,  I strongly recommend you not mix the model view with the graphics scene in such way.

In case it's absolutely impossible to use delegates, I'd think about drawing the lines on `QTableView` — it has API for accessing model indices through pixel coordinates, it does know its scrolling position and it does have handlers for all the necessary user input. So all that you have to do is to store the collection of `QLine` in a class derived from the `QTableView` and draw the lines which fit the current viewport via `QPainter`.
I'm afraid that even if the "overlay" with `QGraphicsScene` looks like the easiest solution now, in the nuts it's tons of issues related to the user input handling/routing. And it's definitely not the Qt-way.

**UPD: a delegate-based sample:**

The idea is quite simple:

- the whole line is a collection of segments — each cell is a
  segment;
- for each cell, map the line `start` and `end` x-coordinate to the
  range [0.0;1.0];
- store mapped coordinates in the model itself.

Then you can draw your custom delegate as follows:

```
void LineDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

    const QVariant &lineData = index.data(Line::DataRole);
    if (lineData.isValid() && lineData.canConvert<Line>()) {
        const Line &line = lineData.value<Line>();
        const QLineF &lineF = line.toQLine(option.rect);
        painter->save();

        painter->setPen(m_linePen);
        painter->drawLine(lineF);

        painter->restore();
    }
}
```

The mouse handling is a bit more tricky:

```
bool LineDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                               const QModelIndex &index)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        handleMousePress(static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event), model, option, index);
        break;
    case QEvent::MouseMove:
        handleMouseMove(static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event), model, option, index);
        break;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        handleMouseRelease(static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event), model, option, index);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return QStyledItemDelegate::editorEvent(event, model, option, index);
}

void LineDelegate::handleMousePress(QMouseEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                    const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    Q_UNUSED(model);

    if (index.isValid()) {
        m_startIndex = index;
        m_startPoint = { event->x() - option.rect.x(), option.rect.center().y() };
    }
}

void LineDelegate::handleMouseMove(QMouseEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                   const QModelIndex &index)
{
    const QPoint endPoint = { event->x() - option.rect.x(), option.rect.center().y() };
    if (m_startIndex != index) {
        m_startIndex = index;
        m_startPoint = endPoint;
    }

    const Line &line = Line::fromQLine({ m_startPoint, endPoint }, option.rect);

    model->setData(index, QVariant::fromValue(line), Line::DataRole);
}

void LineDelegate::handleMouseRelease(QMouseEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                      const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    Q_UNUSED(model);
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(index);

    m_startIndex = QModelIndex();
    m_startPoint = { -1, -1 };
}
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: screencast]

The complete code of the sample above is available on [github](https://github.com/sendevent/linedelegate)

*Please note — that's just a brief prototype. There is no support for things like right-to-left mouse movement, nor limitation to a current row only, etc. But that should be enough for you to start, I hope.*

Comment: I would go the delegate way if it is actually possible to do resizing, selecting and deleting of the drawn line. If you think that is possible, could you please post a small snippet how i can draw using painter and then can access info about the drawn line?

Comment: this a very well made. I started to understand item delegates now. I tested the code and i realized there are many things which would be very difficult to handle if i use this approach. For example, moving mouse too fast, the line becomes choppy, moving mouse back and forth messes up the lines, revisiting the drawn lines and handling mouse events on them and so on. I feel i have better control on the line items with `QGraphicsView` approach.

Comment: I didn't implement tons of things either because I don't know the requirements or because it was just a PoC  
Of course, It's not my place to insist on the usage of delegates. If  you'd prefer to use the scene, I can only add to @ypnos answer:
To avoid drawing on headers/scrollbars you can restrict mouse coordinates in TimelineScene::mouseMoveEvent, see the QTableView::horizontal/verticalHeader(), and QAbstractScrollArea's horizontal/verticalScrollBar() and viewport().
But in case you just have not enough experience with delegates — please don't hesitate to reach me for any help 

Comment: I understand that my question is still incomplete here. That is because i didn't knew there would be so many complications. I created a similar thread https://forum.qt.io/topic/113795/designing-a-custom-timeline-with-mouse-interaction/11 to get some suggestions. Might give you some insight about my requirements. Again thank you for your time and help. I would definitely contact you in case i am stuck. Maybe email or something?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from our discussion about delegates in the comments, to answer your two questions:

### 1. Finding model index from scene coordinates

- Translate the scene coordinate of your line endpoint to a coordinate of your table's QGraphicsWidget by using [`QGraphicsItem::mapFromScene`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mapFromScene).
- Use the translated coordinate with [`QTableView::indexAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#indexAt) to obtain the model index.

### 2. Restricting item movement

You can override `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()` to manipulate any movement of an item even while dragged by the user. It looks like this:

```
QVariant QGraphicsItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change,
                                              const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == ItemPositionChange) {
        // restr.Position() returns a QPointF limited by the allowed are
        return restrictPosition(value.toPointF());
    }
    …
}
```